# Set Go variable with ldflags conflicts with vendor folder

Tags: go, vendor, godeps, ldflags

I'm currently developing a small Go app and I want to set a specific variable (like Version, GitCommit, BuildID...etc.) at build or runtime (with `go build` or `go run`) by using the `-ldflags` option.

Because in my company we have several projects with the same base, I decided to extract the code with these variables in a separate "info" module which could be imported in every project.

Here's my problem, say I'm running the app like this:

`go run -ldflags "-X git.mycompany.com/utils/info.Version=1.0.0" app.go`

This works well, and the variable is set correctly even though the variable is not part of the "main" app but in a dependency.

Then I decided to deploy the app so I used the new `dep` tool to generate the `vendor` folder.
Therefore, the "info" dependency is now in: `vendor/git.mycompany.com/utils/info`

Now when I run the *same* command as above, the said variable (`Version`) is not set anymore.

Am I missing something here ?
As soon as I delete the vendor folder, everything works fine again. It's like this vendor folder is conflicting with the `-ldflags` option or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same problem, after lots of research we stumbled upon the solution in [a comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19000#issuecomment-278502618) to GitHub issue:  [cmd/link: -X doesn't work for vendored packages](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19000).

Solution: the **full** path name, relative to `$GOPATH` should be specified.

It works when developing `git.mycompany.com/utils/info` because the full path is correct.
It doesn't work for vendored dependencies because the **full** path from `$GOPATH` would be like `git.mycompany.com/name-of/package/vendor/git.mycompany.com/utils/info.Version=1.0.0`

Unfortunately, no documentation seem to be present about this ( for further info look at the issue ) but as Dave Cheney points out in a comment:

> this is a side effect of the language way vendoring is implemented